# Cloning an NFC chip, but with some modifications

Tags: nfc

Recently, I accidentally overwrote a bluetooth connection tag in a piece of technology. I have the bluetooth MAC address of the device, but after trying a few apps I cannot seem to find a way to write the tag. When using NFC Tools Pro, it gives me an error and tells me that I am unable to connect to the device. Does anyone know a way to copy over the correct address or to create a whole new tag that performs in the same way? (Pairs to the device when close by and unpairs when tapped again.)

Comment: if you accidentally wrote to the tag, then why are you asking how to write to the tag? ... it seems to me that you already know how to write to a tag .... the other question is ... do you actually know what was the original data on the tag?

Comment: I know the original data, I asked the company to send me over the data and instead they sent me the tag from another pair of the same headphones. Obviously the MAC Address is going to be different as it's a different device, and I can see how the tag is written. (I can see the MAC address of the headphones at the end of the data, or one that looks similair to mine) My question is do you know of an app that will let me clone said data and edit it? NFC Tools was unable to let me edit the app and nor did a few others on the store.

Comment: `do you know of an app that will let me clone said data and edit it?` ... that is a different question from your post ... as such, it does not belong here ... please post at https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

I work with NFC tags. I'm not near my phone but I recall NXP TagWriter can clone. NXP also develops TagInfo. NXP is the semiconductor manufacturer that invented NFC tags with Sony. I'd start with their apps and they also have a support forum if neccessary.

If you want to clone but still need access to selectively edit the NDEF record or other data structures you'll need to use Java with an SDK or do the same and sharpen up your C# skills. Pun intended.